# std::vector and std::min behavior

Tags: c++, stl

Why following program is not returning minimum value as 1.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main ( int argc, char **argv) {
    std::vector<int> test;
    test.push_back(INT_MAX);
    test.push_back(1);

    int min = *(std::min(test.begin(), test.end()));

    std::cout << "Minimum = " << min << std::endl;
}
```

It returns `minimum` values as `2147483647`

Answer (score 48):

You could try this:

```
int min = *std::min_element(test.begin(), test.end());
```

[`std::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min)

*Return the lesser of two arguments
Returns the lesser of a and b. If both are equivalent, a is returned.*

[`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element)

*Returns an iterator pointing to the element with the smallest value in the range [first,last). The comparisons are performed using either operator< for the first version, or comp for the second; An element is the smallest if no other element compares less than it (it may compare equal, though).*

Comment: Ah, this is almost certainly what he wants.

Comment: The return value from `std::min_element()` is an iterator so it needs to be dereferenced.

Comment: Just for completeness, since C++11 `std::min` (and siblings) accept an initialization list. I know it is not a vector, but maybe some readers will find this variant closer to their needs.

Answer (score -1):

Be aware that `std::vector<T>::end()` does NOT give you an iterator to the last element. It returns an iterator pointing BEHIND the last element.
 
If you want to address the first and last element with iterator logic you need to use `(test.begin(), test.end()-1)`.

Comment: This is useful info, but not an answer to the question. Should have been a comment.

Comment: All the algorithms I know from the standard library use an open-end range: [begin, end), ie, they don't consider the _end_ iterator, but just _before_ it. This is also the case of `std::min_element` described in another answer.